# Minecraft Exception Access Violation Problematic Frame ig75icd64.dll

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Minecraft keeps closing a whenever I try to play on multiplayer and its keeps saying that I have a file open. Here is the crash report:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301] [17:43:10] 
[Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Legend_2007 [17:43:10] 
[Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is <censored>) [17:43:13] 
[Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4 [17:43:14] 
[Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default [17:43:16] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem... [17:43:16] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL [17:43:16] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org) [17:43:17] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized. [17:43:17] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started [17:43:25] 
[Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas [17:43:35] 
[Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to play.cubecraft.net, 25565 [17:43:38] 
[Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                                       
# 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# 
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd2ee92177, pid=3040, tid=5852 
# 
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18) 
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x12177] 
# 
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows 
# 
# An error report file with more information is saved as: 
# (i got rid of this part because it showed private info) 
# 
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp 
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. 
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug. 
# AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: sometimes it lets me get onto a sever but when i start to do somethinglike selcect a mode it crashes

Answer (score 4):

This error (ig75icd64.dll) is caused by outdated or broken Intel Graphics Card drivers. Go to https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ to download new ones.

Also, in future, Google search the 'Problematic Frame' in the crash log. Usually (definitely in this case) it will return many results which will solve your problem. For example with this crash, you would search 'ig75icd64.dll'.

Good luck in the future!