# Crashes when joining server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I get this error when I try to join Hypixel, a Minecraft server. I just updated to Windows 10.I'm not using any mods at all. Here's the crash report:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301]
[19:45:31] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Wombatorks
[19:45:34] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[19:45:35] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[19:45:35] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[19:45:36] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[19:45:36] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[19:45:36] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[19:45:36] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[19:45:38] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[19:45:53] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to mc.hypixel.net., 25565
[19:45:57] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[19:45:57] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[19:45:57] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Wombatorks joined.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd55e62177, pid=8508, tid=4976
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x12177]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Locke\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid8508.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: @Frank How do you know it is modded? He even said it wasn't modded at the top. \(0_0)/

Comment: @TheVoidChaos Isn't Hypixel a modded server?

Comment: @Frank Hypixel is a vanilla server. Unless we count plugins as mods?

Comment: @Rivermont Adding anything at all counts as modded. Even Forge.

Comment: @Rivermont anything that is not part of Vanilla. No Chocolate or Strawberry. Not even French Vanilla

Comment: It's actually the `ig75icd64.dll` issue which is a [vanilla issue to do with Intel Drivers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263924/crashes-when-playing-on-servers)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to update your video drivers. Just updating to windows 10 can cause a lot of issues. After that restart, if the issues persist try changing your GPU to your graphics card if you can as an integrated one could be causing the issue.

**Edit:** This also seems to be an issue with intel graphics cards after I've searched around the rest of the site.

If the issues persist I suggest you go to the minecraft forums as they can assist you better than us. This issue isn't fitting the Q&A format.

Comment: yeah, thanks. I noticed this was a duplicate after some searching and am updating my drivers now.

Comment: May I inquire why this was voted down?